# Contest: Best question about "Der Ring des Nibelungen" gets a prize!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, contest

I'm mad and I won't take it anymore. The most sophisticated method of torture known to mankind, masquerading as a SFF work, has no questions on this site!

**CONTEST TIME!**

---

**Contest #1:**

Ask a question about *[Der Ring des Nibelungen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Ring_des_Nibelungen)*, in the next 50 days, and get a chance to enter a contest!

The winner, as judged by me but somewhat influenced by total votes, gets a fabled magical ring. OK, OK, I don't have Joel's angel investors or business acumen, so the winner gets

1. An attaboy from me, with a total worth of $0.02 cents in leperchaun gold
2. An honorable mention in a SFF Blog entry I plan to submit should this contest idea actually work
3. A chance to enter into the Advanced Stakes of Contest #2.

---

**Contest #2:**

Answer a question about *[Der Ring des Nibelungen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Ring_des_Nibelungen)*, in the next 60 days, and get a chance to enter a contest!

The winner, as judged by me but somewhat influenced by total votes, wins:

1. The honor to wear laurels for a month (<sub>laurels supplied by the winner</sub>).
2. A bounty worth 100 reputation from me
3. An even more honorable mention in a SFF Blog entry I plan to submit should this contest idea actually work
4. If the winner of Contest #1 will supply a good answer (in my personal opinion) to any questions about the topic, I shall reward such an answer with a bounty of 100 reputation (but the answer has to be good enough to deserve the bounty).

   - If he also happens to win Contest #2, I will bump the bounty for that win from 100 to 200.

---

If people like the idea, feel free to announce additional prizes/bounties in comments or answers below.

If SE likes the idea, feel free to sweeten the pot with non-leperchaun-gold-backed swag :)

Comment: Small print: contest organizer is ineligible for any consideration of the winning post. Both because it wouldn't be fair, and because he doesn't know all that much about the work in question.

Comment: Believe it or not, I actually had a couple questions to the subject prepared in my mind, but didn't have the time to flesh them out sufficiently to do them justice and also wasn't sure if my work would be met with not-on-topic reactions. Maybe I'll come up with something over the holidays.

Answer (score -2):

What actually killed people after they watched the videotape?

Comment: Der Ring, right? :D